# PowerShell script for windows firewall to automatically set multiple remoteaddress networks?

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall

Basically what I'm trying to do is block all incoming traffic from the internet. Incoming packets from the company's public subnets is okay. Users are able to VPN into the company so there is no use for those machines being public. Currently there is no central firewall running and I am aware of the implications. Working on that but until then I need to fix those Windows firewalls ASAP.

I am trying to close off a dozen PCs and servers with public IP-addresses running Windows 10 and Server 2016 from internet traffic. They are currently open wide to the web without necessity. All they need to be able respond to are two public /16 subnets. Remotedesktop services have already been limited to said subnets, but everything else is wide open and a portscan from outside lit up like a christmas tree in a nightmare.

Thus far I have only been able to close off certain rules like IIS on port 80 and 443 manually via GUI, but there are literally hundreds of rules I'd have to manually adjust to remoteaddresses like '123.123.0.0/16' and '234.234.0.0/16'

Now my experience with powershell is limited. I am able to create, show rules or change them, but not confident enough in order to massively change all the applicable rules via a script. Here's what I do know:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Action Allow -Enabled True -Direction Inbound |
Format-Table -Property Name,
@{Name='Protocol';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol}},
@{Name='LocalPort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort}},
@{Name='RemotePort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).RemotePort}},
@{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
Profile 
-AutoSize
```

Shows me open ports like these, hundreds of them, way too many to change by hand / GUI:

```
Name                                                 Protocol LocalPort             RemotePort RemoteAddress                                             Profile
----                                                 -------- ---------             ---------- -------------                                             -------
IIS-WebServerRole-HTTP-In-TCP                        TCP      80                    Any        {123.123.0.0/255.255.0.0, 234.234.0.0/255.255.0.0}             Any
IIS-WebServerRole-HTTPS-In-TCP                       TCP      443                   Any        {123.123.0.0/255.255.0.0, 234.234.0.0/255.255.0.0}             Any
TSG-UDP-Transport-In-UDP                             UDP      3391                  Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-UDP-1645                               UDP      1645                  Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-UDP-1646                               UDP      1646                  Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-UDP-1812                               UDP      1812                  Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-UDP-1813                               UDP      1813                  Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-DCOM                                   TCP      135                   Any        Any                                                           Any
NPS-NPSSvc-In-RPC                                    TCP      RPC                   Any        Any                                                           Any
SessionDirectoryService-In-TCP                       TCP      RPC                   Any        Any                                                           Any
SessionDirectoryService-RPCSS-In-TCP                 TCP      RPCEPMap              Any        Any                                                           Any
SessionDirectoryService-NP-In-TCP                    TCP      445                   Any        Any                                                           Any
SessionDirectoryService-WMI-DCOM-In-TCP              TCP      135                   Any        Any                                                           Any
SessionDirectoryService-WMI-In-TCP                   TCP      RPC                   Any        Any                                                           Any
TermService-In-TCP                                   TCP      RPC                   Any        {123.123.0.0/255.255.0.0, 234.234.0.0/255.255.0.0}             Any
TermService-RPCSS-In-TCP                             TCP      RPCEPMap              Any        {123.123.0.0/255.255.0.0, 234.234.0.0/255.255.0.0}             Any
```

How would you create a script which analyzes every rule that is
*inbound,
active* and
*allows
remoteport any*,
in order to set it to remoteport {123.123.0.0/255.255.0.0, 234.234.0.0/255.255.0.0}?

Comment: That's a scary proposition.  Are the computers in active directory?  If not, usually the rules are more strict.  Maybe start with the ports that are actively listening in tcpview.